# Can't center my background in Firefox/IE - can't display menu over background HTML

Tags: html, css

Please i need help , im having problems ok first is my bacground image is not showing centerd in firefox or IE but in chrome it works fine and SECOND i ahve amenu and i cant get it to display ontop of my background picture: Below i have pasted my Html code and my css please help me and have a look i would really appreciate it....

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Just something</title>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>




<!-- Start css3menu.com HEAD section -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bcg_files/css3menu1/style.css" type="text/css" />
<!-- End css3menu.com HEAD section -->

</head>

<body align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">

<div id="wrapper" >


        <div id="menu" class="menu" style="z-index:900;">
         <ul id="css3menu1" class="topmenu">
                                <li class="topfirst">
                                    <a href="#" title="Home" style="height:15px;line-height:15px;">Home</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="topmenu">
                                    <a href="#" title="Product Information" style="height:15px;line-height:15px;">
                                        <span>Product Information</span>
                                    </a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="subfirst"><a href="#" title="MAXOFIX">MAXOFIX</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" title="Splicing">Splicing</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" title="Sidewalls">Sidewalls</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" title="Cleats">Cleats</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" title="Basebelts">Basebelts</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" title="Accessories">Accessories</a></li>
                                </ul>

                                </li>

                                <li class="topmenu">
                                    <a href="#" title="Downloads" style="height:15px;line-height:15px;">
                                        <span>Downloads</span>
                                    </a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="subfirst"><a href="#" title="Catalogues">Catalogues</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" title="Mobile App.">Mobile App.</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" title="Enquiries">Enquiries</a></li>
                                </ul>

              </li>
                                <li class="toplast"><a href="#" title="Contacts" style="height:15px;line-height:15px;">Contacts</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>



<!--This where the menu will start -->
<!--img src="ok heres my img"  style="z-index:3;" align="middle" width="864" height="1152" alt=""-->  




<!-- The following Div's are for te boxes at the bottom of the page
     you can edit the text in the paragraph just as you want for the
     the ease of editing........lol -->

<!-- box left-->
            <div id="cc_content1" class="cc_content1">
                            <!--span id="cc_back" class="cc_back">&lt;&lt; Go back</span-->
                            <div class="cc_content_1">
                                    <h1>Advantages:</h1>
                                    <p>
                                        Space-saving Inclines of up to <br />
                                        90(and then that small 0) possible.<br />
                                        Belts are easy on material<br />
                                        transported.<br />
                                        Direction of feed and dis-<br />
                                        charge can be different.
                                        <br /><br />
                                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com" title="To what ever page it is that you want">More...</a>
                                    </p>
                            </div>

  </div>



<!--This ends box to the far left -->


<!-- box mid-->
<div id="cc_content" class="cc_content">
                        <!--span id="cc_back" class="cc_back">&lt;&lt; Go back</span-->
                        <div class="cc_content_1">
                            <h1>Products:</h1>
                            <p>
                                Space-saving Inclines of up to <br />
                                        90(and then that small 0) possible.<br />
                                        Belts are easy on material<br />
                                        transported.<br />
                                        Direction of feed and dis-<br />
                                        charge can be different.
                                        <br /><br />
                                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com" title="To what ever page it is that you want">More...</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>

  </div>

<!--This ends box in the midd -->




<!-- box right-->
            <div id="cc_content2" class="cc_content2">
                 <!--span id="cc_back" class="cc_back">&lt;&lt; Go back</span-->
                    <div class="cc_content_1">
                        <h1>News:</h1>
                        <p>  Space-saving Inclines of up to <br />
                                        90(and then that small 0) possible.<br />
                                        Belts are easy on material<br />
                                        transported.<br />
                                        Direction of feed and dis-<br />
                                        charge can be different.
                                        <br /><br />
                                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com" title="To what ever page it is that you want">More...</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>

            </div>
        <!--This ends box far right  -->         

</div>

</body>
</html>



HERE IS MY CSS


/* this is for the main page */

/*this is for the menu*/ 
.menu
{
    align:center;
    left:567px;
}



/*This is for the boxes at the bottom of the pag*/
.cc_content
{

    width:233px;
    height:236px;
    /*border-bottom:1px solid #000;*/
    position:absolute;
    left:567px;
    overflow:hidden;
    /*-moz-box-shadow:4px 0 7px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:4px 0 7px #000;
    box-shadow:4px 0 7px #000;*/
    top:876px;
}

.cc_content1
{
    width:233px;
    height:236px;
    /*border-bottom:1px solid #000;*/
    position:absolute;
    left:328px;
    overflow:hidden;
    /*-moz-box-shadow:4px 0 7px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:4px 0 7px #000;
    box-shadow:4px 0 7px #000;*/
    top:  876px;
}


.cc_content2
{
    width:233px;
    height:236px;
    /*border-bottom:1px solid #000;*/
    position:absolute;
    left:806px;
    overflow:hidden;
    /*-moz-box-shadow:4px 0 7px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:4px 0 7px #000;
    box-shadow:4px 0 7px #000;*/
    top:  876px;
}



/*This is for the content of the boxes exept the Header*/
.cc_content p
{
    background:none;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:15px;
}

.cc_content1 p
{
    background:none;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:15px;
}
.cc_content2 p
{
    background:none;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:15px;
}





/*This is for the Header of the boxes*/
.cc_content h1
{
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:15px;
}

.cc_content1 h1
{
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:15px;
}

.cc_content2 h1
{
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:15px;
}


I HAVE A CUSTOM CSS3 MENU BUT I DONT THINK THAT IS THE PROBLEM..
```

Answer (score 1):

z-index is ignored unless the div is `position: relative` or `absolute`, make sure it is one of these otherwise the z-index is pointless

Comment: thanx i will keep that in mind , i still cant get it to work tho..??

Comment: ok mmmm i fixed that and now my custom menu is displaying over my backgroundimage but still no alignment in firefox or IE ??oh and btw thank you very much